# My GameScene is not positioned correctly after switching scene

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, position, scene

[Image of weirdly positioned sccene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ede0o.png)

So Before i made the start scene, my gamescene worked perfectly. but now it isnt. why? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `scene.anchorPoint`, maybe you accidentally changed it. Default is `CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)`.

Comment: Instance member 'anchorPoint' cannot be used on type 'SKScene'. i dont know :/